# Rspec checking ActiveModel::Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Is there a better way to write this spec? This works ***but*** I don't like the fact that I have to call `f.valid?` to get f.errors to populate.

```
it "fails to save the record because the name is blank" do
  f = Foo.new
  f.valid?
  f.errors.include?(:name).should be_true
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
it "fails to save the record because the name is blank" do
  Foo.create.errors.should include :name
end
```